tensorflow model.fit vs model.evaluate give conflicting results
Using tensorflow, I have a trained multi-ouput regression model so that when I run model.evaluate(X,Y) I get an accuracy of 1.0. Being suspicious of perfection, I tried model.predict(X) thinking that this should be similar to Y. This returns something that is ~55% similar to Y.
My questions:

How does model.evaluate() determine accuracy for regression models?
Because I am trying to train a multi-output regression model, is there anything special that I need to do to prevent tensorflow from interpreting this as a classification problem??

Below is a snippet from my code:
`
model = simple_model()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

logdir="logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=3, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X,  Y, verbose=2)
print(test_acc)

`
Thank you for taking time to read this.
Best Regards!
Things that I have tried:
Because the accuracy is reported as 1 (meaning 100%) I was suspicious that the model.evaluate() is somehow treating my model as a classification problem when I hoped it would be a regression problem. By using model.predict() for the same data that allegedly was 100% accurate, I did not get good results.
I believe that there may be some subtle way my model is structured, forcing it to be a classification model when I really desire it to be a regression model.

No, this is totally wrong, you are assuming things and then asking us about what you assumed. To start, you should not be using  accuracy for a regression model. And why are you using a classification loss for regression? that will also not work.

We cannot comment on the way your model is structured, because you did not provide information on your model (nor on the data). See Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@Dr.Snoopy , thank you for pointing me in the right direction. How should I change model.Compile() so that is is for a regression model?

Actually, I think I see my tragic flaw ...
I need to use soemthing like:
model.compile(
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
loss='mean_absolute_error')
